# Tense of subordinate clause after "I confirmed that"

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-perfect, present-tense, tense-agreement

Which is best among the following sentences, and why?

1. I confirmed that now the page was updated.
2. I confirmed that now the page is updated.
3. I confirmed that now the page has been updated.

Comment: It depends, HAL. Do you mean "I confirmed now that the page * updated" or "I confirmed that the page * updated now."

Comment: (1) doesn't make sense. (3) is best if the update was made recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression 'is updated' can be understood in two ways:
- *passive* (describes an action): undergoes (sporadically/regularly) an update process
- *perfect* (describes a state): has undergone an update process i.e. is in the state of having undergone an update process

In the reported speech, things being reported can remain in the present tense if they remain valid in the present.

**(1)** Both 'confirmed' and 'was updated' are in the past tense. 'now' makes no sense here.
In order to be timely and logically correct, the sentense should go like:
*passive*/*perfect*: I confirmed that then/at that time the page was updated.

**(2)** The sentence is correct, but is - due to the used present simple tense - only able to report the passive aspect.
*passive*: I confirmed that now the page is updated (sporadically/regularly).

Notice: The passive voice doesn't seem to be the preferred option for English-speaking people. That's why this option, perhaps, comes to mind less often, although grammatically correct.

**(3)** The sentence is correct but is only able to report the perfect aspect. The used present perfect tense renders better the fulfillment of the update action.
*perfect*: I confirmed that now the page has been updated. Once - that's for sure, but not necessarily again in the future.

So, both (2) and (3) are correct. They just express different situations.